React Tostify toast is not working for me
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';  import { Bounce, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
I have imported successfully.
And also rendered in the App component.
        `<ToastContainer
            position="top-right"
            autoClose={5000}
            hideProgressBar={false}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
            theme="light"
            transition={Bounce}
        />`

But the toast notification is not working!
Would you help???
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';  import { Bounce, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
I have imported successfully.
And also rendered in the App component.
         `<ToastContainer
            position="top-right"
            autoClose={5000}
            hideProgressBar={false}
            newestOnTop={false}
            closeOnClick
            rtl={false}
            pauseOnFocusLoss
            draggable
            pauseOnHover
            theme="light"
            transition={Bounce}
        />`


where  is your toast function
